# Why use spectrograms in recent neural network speech recognition systems?

Tags: speech-recognition, recurrent-neural-network, spectrogram

Why use spectrograms in recent neural network speech recognition systems (https://github.com/SeanNaren/CTCSpeechRecognition) as opposed to learning the spectrogram transformation with a neural network layer?

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 4):

If you know something about features, it's often useful to use this information instead of relying on learning it.

For example it is known that only signal energy is important for speech recognition and signal phase is not important. That is why using spectrogram is preferred compared to plain signal, you just use important information and drop non-important. Energy computation requires square and it is not easy to learn with a single layer, you need either several layers or you need a special nonlinearity.

It is actually even better to go further and use log-filterbank, it produces even more compact features with same prediction quality.

There are cases where phase is important, one of them is recognition of mixed sources where you can separate sources based on phase information, something like DIET algorithm is doing. But until such problems are considered for speech recognition spectrogram is used.